# Android: why am i always getting the first intent from push notifications?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, onnewintent

I'm making a push notification service for my news app, i'm sending a notification from my php server using the new GoogleCloudMessaging (GCM), when the message arrives to the phone, my app catches the message and make a notification out of it, when you click on the notification it will take you to the DemoActivity(which is the main activity in this demo app) and display the text in a TextView. Now this works perfectly for the first message i send from my server, but when i send messages after the first one, they reach the phone and my app makes a notification correctly but when i click on the notification it always displays the first message.

Here's my code:

This is DemoActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    /**
     * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
     * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
     */
    String SENDER_ID = "Sender id";

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    String notificationText;

    String regid;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        context = getApplicationContext();





        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        //  GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }

    }
    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
        // the new app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the registration ID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(DemoActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                    // is using accounts.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                    // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the registration ID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your server-side implementation here.
    }
    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }
    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    // You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            notificationText = extras.getString("theMsg");
            mDisplay.setText(notificationText);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is GCMBroadcastReceiver:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

And this GCMIntentService:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;


import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;


    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }



    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {



        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString(), "");
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString(), "");
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                /*for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }*/
                //Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received a notification");
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification(extras.get("price").toString(), extras.get("id").toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.



    private void sendNotification(String msg, String id) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("theMsg",msg);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                0,
                notificationIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

And this is the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fm.ana.officialgcmtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="fm.ana.officialgcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="fm.ana.officialgcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".NotificationHandler" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="fm.ana.officialgcmtest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I made some researches and i found that i have to tell the app to get the new intent when calling getIntent() but i'm having trouble doing that correctly.

Anyone can help with that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) it mean a lot of stuff (please see link for more inof) but the most important in your case is that when an activity was already created it wont be recreated anymore but instead it will be brought back to the front stack and resumed with the new intent.

In your demo activity the getIntent is called only when the activity is created (and that happen only once not matter how much the user click to the notification base on the flag you passed on the intent)

So in order to get new intent when the user click to the notification please override the onNewIntent(Intent intent);

Example

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            notificationText = extras.getString("theMsg");
            mDisplay.setText(notificationText);
        }

    }
```

And you can even remove that line in your onCreate() method. Voila! i believe that it should work now.

Good luck!
Edit: in order for it work properly you need to set your intent flags as follow:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Also don't remove the line from onCreate as you will need it in case you get notification and your activity was not created yet.

Comment: i tried it, didn't work, i updated my DemoActivity if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: Can you check first the msg your getting from the push notification before you pass it the intent? Just to make sure that your doing it right from there

Comment: Actually now it doesn't work at all not even the first message, the LogCat shows that the device received a message and the notification is created correctly but clicking on the notification now does nothing not even the first message.

Comment: Can you please change your pending intent flag to :FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT ? instead of FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT before you send the notification

Comment: I tried, the notifications is created but clicking on it will not do anything not even the first one.

Comment: The newIntent is not fire because there is something probably wrong with your flags .

Please try to set this flag on the intent intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72241/discussion-between-murieldotcmr-and-fadi-obaji).